# Aligning Bootstrap Grids in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Currently I have Bootstrap Grids in one page as shown in the picture below.

[My Bootstrap Grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wryb5.png)

And I want grid as shown in picture below with red indicator

[Wanted my Bootstrap Grid Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR8XI.png)

**Codes**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>My label</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>My label</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>My label</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>My label</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem, your 4 grids matches as per referance

Comment: if i add another grid, it will align to the left, as you can see my second picture, I wanted to make it in the middle. I could make col-md-12 but it took  the whole left and right spaces

Comment: add the  `col-offset-md-3` class to your last div to offset it to the middle

Comment: Your new div would have the classes `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes this is what im looking for! Thank you very much. Can you post it as answer so that i could vote ur answer as the best for my future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Add some offset to your last col, like :

```
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>My label</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: tried your code, it align in the center but the borders went all the way to the right

Comment: Can you link a screenshot ?

Comment: Link to the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/k5yf3kh.png (Im using the one you posted before edited) Somehow the borders didnt stretch out the second time i did it :\